# What is the origin of using particular initials such as AJ, JJ etc as a first name?

Tags: history, names, initialisms

In the English language (and predominantly American English), it is relatively common to see a (limited) set of first and middle names that form initials used as a shortened version of the given names. (ex. TJ, JT, DJ). Thomas John Washington becomes TJ Washington. Where does this practice come from and why those handful of specific initials?

Comment: It comes from people who wanted a shorter way to refer to someone.

Comment: You mean, why is it that some initials seem to be preferentially used (as in "tee jay" for the initials T J) and others (eg, "ess are" for  S R) are not?  Because "tee jay" just has a snappy sound to it.

Comment: *Where does this practice come from?* - I cannot imagine what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Are you referring to people who are commonly addressed by their initials? I'm not aware that this is limited to particular letters. People's nicknames evolve within their family for all sorts of reasons, not necessarily logical.

Comment: @Kate There is absolutely a finite set of these that stays relatively constant over the course of decades. No one is named "S.R.", "Z.Q.", or "L.B.".

Comment: @Drew Etymology is one of the most common categories of questions here. Is it your first day?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not really a question about the language itself, but of a particular social convention; I would consider it a form of hypocorism. I would dispute that it is "relatively common," however; if anything, the practice has declined sharply since the mid-20th century, when name diversity increased and the need to include middle initials to distinguish between 10 Williams or 10 Marys in intimate situations declined.

Comment: @choster You would be hard pressed to argue that my question doesn't fall under the "U" part of EL&U.

Comment: I’ve upvoted, because this is an excellent question, and one which I have wondered about myself: why is it specifically those three sets of initials that are so common? However, you should edit the question to be more specific about what your research has been: what you’ve searched for, what articles you’ve found and read, etc. You may also want to specify that this is a very _American_ phenomenon—notably, I believe Kate and choster, who do not recognise the central point, are both British, which explains why it doesn’t ring a bell with them. (Or maybe choster isn’t…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not really sure what more to say about the research. There's nothing. No one has asked this question before on any forum on the internet. No official repositories of etymology or initialisms have info on using them as nicknames. There's nothing

Comment: @WakeDemons3 Well, there are some indirect pieces of evidence. [This page](http://thestir.cafemom.com/pregnancy/181279/tell_baby_gender_sonogram_ultrasound) gives a bunch of names that make for good initials, and these all confirm to my instinctive ideas of common initial-names. Then there’s [this page](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/01/14/two-letter-initials-which-are-the-most-common.html) where someone made a heat map of the most common initials—you can compare and see if name combinations that match the common initial-names are particularly common, for instance.

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57849/why-is-the-letter-j-so-common-in-names-of-people-who-go-by-their-initials)

Comment: @Dispenser My question asks for an etymological answer, which isn't nearly as subjective.

Comment: See related information (possibly speculative) at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnlyKnownByInitials

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a hard time finding sources for this, thus all of the following is from my own head.

A name like JT can come from having a given name they would rather not use, and a first + middle name that says JT, or JR, or anything else. Hyphenated first names aren't very common in English speaking countries but someone might also abbreviate something like Jean-Baptiste into JB.

If the second letter is J, in my experience it almost always refers to "junior". The reason someone might be called DJ is because they were named after their father named Douglas, David, whatever, and instead of others in the family calling both people the same name, they call one a shortened version. Maybe Doug, maybe David, but also maybe DJ (Doug Junior).

Comment: You acknowledge that you don't have sources, which I understand. But I've never heard of that first part. Every TJ, BJ, or DJ I've met has had a J middle name, making the letters initials. Like "Thomas John Lastname". I've never heard of a Junior being the J, and that would be structurally different than my question.

Comment: I knew a lot of guys named Chris and David growing up, some of them ended up as CJ or DJ not because their middle name was a J middle name, but because they were Juniors. That's purely off personal experience, specifically experiences from elementary to high school, a while back. Some people did have J initals from their middle name, but not all, in my experience.